# Understanding steps for integrating standard normal distribution using polar coordinates

Tags: integration, normal-distribution, polar-coordinates

I have the following derivation for showing that the integral of the standard normal distribution is equal to one.

I don't completely understand the steps so I'll provide the derivation and then write what I think is happening.

$$
\begin{align}
  2\pi \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} p(x) dx
  &= 2\pi \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} p(x) dx \tag{1} \\
  &= 2 \pi \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} p(x) dx
           \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} p(y) dy \tag{2}\\
  &= \int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(x^2+y^2)/2}dx\ dy \tag{3}\\
  &= \int\limits_{\theta=0}^{2\pi} \int\limits_{r=0}^\infty e^{-r^2/2} r\ dr\ d\theta \tag{4} \\
  &= 2\pi \tag{5}
\end{align}
$$

1. Is what we're trying to integrate (wasn't included in the text but I added it for clarity). I think both sides should be multiplied by $2\pi$ which we do to make the leap in (3) easier so I included that.
2. We're multiplying by the integral in terms of $y$. I think the argument is that this is similar to multiplying by 1, but I'm not fully satisfied by this because we're supposed to be proving that. I think this fallacy is called "begging the question".
3. Integration is commutative. I'm comfortable with the inside argument but I'm not sure why the $2\pi $ got consumed.
4. We converted to polar coordinates. No problem here.
5. Evaluate the integral. No problem here.

So as was explained earlier I'm worried about **begging the question** in (2) and I don't know why the $\boldsymbol{2\pi}$ got consumed in (3).

Comment: This solution is posted on dozens of websites.  Do a simple Google search.

Comment: If I'm not mistaking, [this](https://www.math.ucla.edu/~archristian/teaching/32b-sum18/session-2.pdf) doesn't answer my question, nor does [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0pXcKrQqMa0&ab_channel=LorenzoSadun), unfortunately [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bjh5Yvml4RM&ab_channel=AStatisticalPath) doesn't either, and finally neither does [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HcneBkidSDQ&ab_channel=DrPeyam). You'll notice I asked specific questions about the derivation, not for a general explanation found elsewhere

Comment: i think the $2\pi$ got consumed by the coefficient of the two standard normal distributions (which is $1/\sqrt{2\pi}$ each).

Comment: I think I agree with you though, the step (2) is a fallacy. From this wiki page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_integral, there is a better proof, which starts by squaring the firstmost integral

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $I$ be the value of the integral. Then get rid of line (1), and on the left hand side of equation (2) write $2\pi I^2 = ...$.

You end up with $2\pi I^2 = 2\pi$. Then solve for $I$, using the fact that $I \ge 0$.